# How to copy (or view) current directory/folder's name, via command line (macOS)

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, command-line-interface

Not to be confused with the `pwd` as that command outputs the entire path to the present working directory.  I only need the present directory/folder's name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it with `echo "${PWD##*/}"`

or `printf '%s\n' "${PWD##*/}"`

Sourced: https://askubuntu.com/questions/375395/bash-get-current-working-directory-name-but-not-full-path